# Power Automate: Update a value in the "current" row in Excel

Tags: excel, office365, power-automate

I am using Microsoft 365 Power Automate to do a mail merge from Excel:

I have a simple mail merge flow, wherein I `List rows present in a table` and then I go inside `Apply to each` and for each row, I read the email address and a few merge fields to generate and send an email. After sending the email, I want to set a flag in the current row so that looking at the Excel, I can quickly see which people have been emailed.

`Update a row` action seems to be an overkill (and also inefficient) as it asks me to pick a file and table and find a row to update etc. Is there a way to tell Power Automate to just update the row it is reading inside the `Apply to each`?

Comment: No, you have to do the work with the approach you’re using. They’re all separate operations, one doesn’t necessarily know about the other. The apply to each doesn’t even know you’re reading  Excel data, to it, it’s just an array of data.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be too much work to keep track of which row you are working on. Within your `Apply to each`, set a variable to keep track of the current row. Then in the `Update a row` activity, you can just use that variable.

Small sample with a table that has 2 columns: Name and Updated. Create a variable `current_name`. As you loop through each row, assign the Name column value to the variable `current_name`.

[image]

[image]

Within the `Apply to each` loop, `Update a row` using the Name column as the Key Column, and the `current_name` as the Key Value.

You only have to enter the file and table name once, and no need to "find" the current row. It does seem like overkill and inefficient because Power Automate might be re-connecting to the file for each row, but it's also pretty fast.

[image]